# Can Apache Tomcate server run PHP file by default?

Tags: tomcat

I am beginner in Tomcat server and just started working with Tomcat server.I want to run a **PHP file in Tomcat server**. is it possible by default ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't by default. Try using somthing like this: http://php-java-bridge.sourceforge.net/doc/tomcat6.php

Comment: Thankz for your answer. I want to read a excel file from tomcat server using **PHP javabridge**